# How to modify the total width in a tufte-book using includemp?

Tags: geometry, width, tufte

I'am working on a tufte-book document class and I want to change the size of the page. As the page are smaller, I want to fix the total width of the text (including the marginal notes).
The documentation of the document class specifies using the geometry package.

In the documentation of this package, the `width` parameter is explained as follows:

> `width|totalwidth`
>
> width of *total body*. `width=` or `totalwidth=`. This dimension defaults to `textwidth`, but if
> `includemp` is set to `true`, `width ≥ textwidth` because `width` includes the width of the marginal notes. If `textwidth` and `width` are specified at
> the same time, `textwidth` takes priority over `width`.

This is the text in my preamble :

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{geometry,afterpage}
\geometry{papersize={16.8cm,23.7cm}}% <= it seems to be OK
\geometry{textheight=18.6cm}%text : 132 *186 mm <= it is OK
\geometry{width=13.2cm}% <= The code doesn't take into account the marginparwidth and the marginparsep

\begin{document}

\end{document]
```

I don't know how to specify that `includemp` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotation from the `geometry` manual says "If `textwidth` and `width` are specified at the same time, `textwidth` takes priority over `width`".

In the source for `tufte-book`, specifically the file `tufte-common.def`, the following code is present:

```
\RequirePackage[letterpaper,left=1in,top=1in,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=26pc,marginparsep=2pc,marginparwidth=12pc,textheight=44\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip]{geometry}
```

This means that `textwidth` is specified in the class, and therefore that any `width` specifications given later (for example in the `.tex` file) are ignored.

To change the width of the text therefore you need to specify `textwidth` and take the margin size into account manually. However, arithmetic expressions can be used in `\geometry`. Therefore the following code

```
\geometry{textwidth=13.2cm-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep}
```

specifies that the main text and the margin combined are 13.2cm.